# What font is this, and how can I use it with pdfLaTeX?

Tags: fonts

What font is this, and how can I use it with pdfLaTeX? I have tried with Acrobat Reader and I get Times New Roman, but I think that this is slightly different from that.

http://plankt.oxfordjournals.org/content/31/9/1059.full.pdf

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a rather poor digitization of a Baskerville, with the wispy strokes that so many Baskerville digitizations from the early 90s suffer from. Among the most idiosyncratic glyphs in Baskervilles are the `g`, the `W` and the `C`. This particular digitization is the one from Monotype. ITC's version is okay-ish, but the only one that's actually good is the one from [Storm Type.](http://www.stormtype.com/services/get_pdf.php?family_id=114) Mrs Eaves from Emigre is beautiful, but too fancy for lengthy reading. A number of ›free‹ Baskervilles are floating around as well, but [sorry!] none of them can keep up with the professional ones.

PS: Times New Roman is only one of a dozen fonts used in that document. The others aren't as easily recognized because of their obfuscated names -- which often are a result of customizations that the font user commissioned to the foundry. Oxford UP may, for example, have Monotype include additional symbols in their Baskerville, or modify others. Quite a common practice actually.

PPS: how can you use it with pdfLaTeX? Obtain a license for the font you want to use;  check if someone has already written pdfTeX support for that font; if no one has, use `otftotfm` and `autoinst` to produce that support yourself, based on the OpenType (!) version of that font [check if the EULA permits conversion from OpenType to Type1 first, for that's necessary in pdfTeX].

Comment: Just curious: how did you see so fast that it is Monotype's?

Comment: The proportions are different in Monotype's vs. ITC's. ITC's also is a bit sturdier. And slightly more playful. And then there's individual glyph shapes. See, for example, the `a` or the `5` in the two versions: [ITC](http://www.identifont.com/samples/itc/NewBaskerville.gif) and [MT.](http://www.identifont.com/samples/monotype/Baskerville.gif)